# Route Function is not working on Start Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying to implement URL Routing in ASP.Net Web Forms (For the first time) with the help of a solution i found on a website [ [download the solution](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Handlers/DownloadFile.ashx?File=3beaf303-2aeb-4f90-bfd7-7c997314814b.zip) ] . Route is working except my `Start Page` .

For example , If I set `Home.aspx` as start page, url is `http://localhost:49200/Home.aspx` and other pages say, `Modifications` appears as `http://localhost:49200/Modifications` route works on other pages . 
 And if i set `Modifications` as start page url becomes `http://localhost:49200/Modifications.aspx` and `Home` becomes `http://localhost:49200/Home`.Why is that ??

**Global.asax**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace Test
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
     {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "Home","~/Home.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("Modifications", "Modifications","~/Modifications.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("AccountClosing", "AccountClosing","~/AccountClosing.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Do i need to do anything on config ? 
menu is in `'<%=ResolveUrl("~/Home") %>'` format.! Please help to solve this problem..